# Exchanging String between devices over Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, unique-key

> I am beginner and making my first project on android studio. I want to exchange a unique string between devices over Bluetooth without pairing whenever devices are near. Following is the code I tried but did not work. The code I mention is of scanning part only when click on scan it search for the device and exchange the keys but it is not working.

```
     @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                ON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                OFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
                Scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
                myBT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                Interaction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intr);
                intentON = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                other = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                bluelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.btList);
                //IntView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.InList);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                pAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                bluelist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        
                random = UUID.randomUUID();
                getUUID = random.toString();
                code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SomeNumbers");
                code.setText(data);
                send = (String) code.getText();
        
                checkPermission();
        
                ON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
        
                        if(myBT.isEnabled())
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth already Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            bluetoothOn();
                    }
                });
        
                OFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        bluetoothOff();
                    }
                });
        
                Scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        discover();
                    }
                });
                bluelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //pairDevice(device);
                    }
                });
                Interaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent getInteractions = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interactions.class);
                        //Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        //args.putSerializable("Exposure", (Serializable)arrayList);
                        getInteractions.putStringArrayListExtra("Exposure", arrayList);
                        startActivity(getInteractions);
                    }
                });
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (requestCode == BLUETOOTH_REQ_CODE) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        
            private void discover(){
                if(myBT.isDiscovering()){
                    myBT.cancelDiscovery();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Discovery stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    if(myBT.isEnabled()) {
                        arrayAdapter.clear(); // clear items
                        myBT.startDiscovery();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        
                    }
                    else{
                        bluetoothOn();
                    }
                }
            }
        
            private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                        device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        // add the name to the list
                        arrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        ServerClass serverClass = new ServerClass();
                        serverClass.start();
                        ClientClass clientClass = new ClientClass(pairing);
                        clientClass.start();
                        sendReceive.write(send.getBytes());
                    }
                }
            };
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what)
            {
                case STATE_LISTENING:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Listening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                    byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj ;
                    String tempMsg = new String(readBuff,0,msg.arg1);
                    other.setText(tempMsg);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    private class ServerClass extends Thread
    {
        private BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

        public ServerClass()
        {
            try {
                serverSocket = myBT.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(App_Name,random);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run()
        {
            BluetoothSocket socket=null;
            while(socket == null)
            {
                try {
                    //Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    //msg.what=
                    //handler.sendMessage(msg);

                    socket=serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    //msg.what=
                    //handler.sendMessage(msg);

                }
                if(socket != null)
                {
                    //Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    //msg.what=
                    //handler.sendMessage(msg);

                    sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                    sendReceive.start();
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ClientClass extends Thread
    {
        private BluetoothDevice device;
        private BluetoothSocket socket;

        public ClientClass(BluetoothDevice device1)
        {
            device=device1;
            try {
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(random);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                socket.connect();
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SendReceive extends Thread
    {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            bluetoothSocket=socket;
            InputStream tempIn = null;
            OutputStream tempOut = null;

            try {
                tempIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tempOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            inputStream = tempIn;
            outputStream = tempOut;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    handler.obtainMessage(STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes)
        {
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey there, can you edit the question to include what you've tried and it would be really useful to include code. Bluetooth devices and connections can be very complicated and confusing.

Comment: Hey, I add my work please check it.

Comment: Appoligies, as I'm not that familar with Android Native bluetooth. In adition to the source code you've added, it could be useful to add any error messages you are seeing on the console.
If you are running your code from android studio it should be printed in a terminal type window. Error codes and messages are often crucial to solving the issue.
The first step is usually to google the specif error message and see if it's been posted anywhere online.

Comment: The next step is usually to step through the code using breakpoints and determinging exactly which line of your code is causing the error.

Comment: I am not getting any error, only problem is that it is not working and i can't find the mistake (may be in syntax or may be something is missing).